# VB.NET Add Text after an specified line of a text file

Tags: vb.net

How is it possible to add a text after(or before) an specified line of a text file with vb.net ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Add a text after Line 5 to the Textfile just call:

```
AppendAtPosition("C:\Temp\test.txt", 5, "contenttoappend")
```

To add a text before Line 5 to the Textfile just call

```
AppendAtPosition("C:\Temp\test.txt", 4, "contenttoappend")
```

This Function is needed:

If the Textfile has fewer lines than you expect, the content will be added after the last line.

```
Private Sub AppendAtPosition(ByVal ltFilePath As String, ByVal liAppendLine As Integer, ByVal ltAppendLine As String)

    Dim ltFileContents As String = ""
    Dim lReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ltFilePath)
    Dim liRow As Integer = 0

    While Not lReader.EndOfStream
      ltFileContents &= lReader.ReadLine
      If liRow = liAppendLine Then
        ltFileContents &= ltAppendLine
        Exit While
      End If
      liRow += 1
    End While
    If liAppendLine >= liRow Then
      ltFileContents &= ltAppendLine
    End If
    File.WriteAllText(ltFilePath, ltFileContents)
End Sub
```

Comment: So it was requested to add text at a specific line, and also discard all text after that line? Or should the remaining text be moved further down?